# Вопрос о пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

*Откуда я знаю?! Может(,) это  твоя...*

Comment: Пишите фразу целиком!

Answer (score 1):

Вводное слово МОЖЕТ стоит в самом начале отдельного предложения, поэтому **запятая ставится.**

Ср.: ***Я не знаю, может твоя...*** Здесь МОЖЕТ стоит после главного, в начале придаточного предложения - запятая не ставится. Это позволяет безоговорочно отнести вводное слово ко второму предложению.

Answer (score 0):

Откуда я знаю?! Может, это твоя...

Запятая после *может* ставится, так как это вводное слово (возможно, вероятно). Ещё убрала пробел перед знаком вопроса.